# How to checkout an svn repository to your local machine

Tags: svn

I am using putty with my university Id and password  to give svn  commands.
I have to upload a file from my local machine into repository. 
I tried svn import and file name while in the directory where I have to upload the file. 
Svn import c:/users/gh/file.txt
But I get an error that its invalid url .

I tried if I can checkout file to the local machine, edit it and then add the changes 
I used svn co https: 
But it checkout into the terminal but not into the local machine. 
I am very new to svn . Can someone tell what am I doing wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. "putty with my university Id" means (at least) SSH-access to remote host and nohow define existence and accessibility of http-based SVN-server. You *may* have `svn+ssh://` access, **if it's configured** at server side (ask admin for possibility and credentials)
2. You **must** to read description of [`svn import`](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.8/svn.ref.svn.c.import.html) command at least and get *all* needed parameters in order to use command properly in remote shell. For `svn import [PATH] URL` you miss URL (of real repository) definition. Ask admin about it